# Как подвинуть нижний край экрана, на высоту размера баннера adMob

Tags: java, android

Как подвинуть нижний край экрана, на высоту размера баннера adMob

Сам баннер

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            ...>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Класс для загрузки баннера

```
public class Ads {
    // создаем метод для создания баннера
    public static void showBanner(final Activity activity) {

        // создаем баннер, находим его по id
        final AdView banner = (AdView) activity.findViewById(R.id.banner);
        // строит и загружает баннер
        // импорт android.gms.ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        banner.loadAd(adRequest);

        // слушатель загрузки баннера
        banner.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                setupContentViewPadding(activity, banner.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }

    // метод подвигает нижний край экрана, на высоту размера баннера
    public static void setupContentViewPadding(Activity activity, int padding) {
        View view = activity.findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        view.setPadding(view.getPaddingLeft(), view.getPaddingTop(), view.getPaddingRight(), padding);
    }
}
```

И в самом Активити

```
Ads.showBanner(this);
```

Раньше беннер отлично подвигал все содержимое на вверх, сейчас видимо после каких-то обновлений, не сдвигаем вверх и соответственно закрывает собой содержимое.

Comment: Вы бы layout полностью скинули, а то так не понятно. Мне во всяком случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Использовать контекст в методах static можно получить Leak.*

примерно так он не будет пересекаться с основным контентом

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:
android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_detail"
    style="?attr/layoutBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >


        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearBus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ViewStub
                    android:id="@+id/viewStub"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges = "true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:inflatedId="@+id/inflate"
                    android:layout="@layout/view_stub_layout" />



                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_2"
                    style="?attr/myCardViewStyle"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx5"
                            style="@style/textMain"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsun" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Я немного по другому сделал, но спасибо за ответ)